# Rendering form input fields inline across all browsers

Tags: html, css

I wanted to position form text input field and a submit button inline like so (as seen on Chrome):

[image]

I achieved the intended positioning by applying these rules (simplified markup and css):

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input class="email-input" type="email">
    </div>
    <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Join now">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

However, on Firefix (31.0) I get this:

[image]

The CSS rules and markup I used are very straightforward, but they're failing.

How could I make the form render correctly across all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need `div` then remove it and add `id` or `class` to `input` for CSS selectors, and then `inline-block` the `input`.

For your HTML code align the inputs vertically, if needed, also align the wrapper vertically.

```
input {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Optional: I would also suggest to reset CSS at first point.

Comment: Only getting rid of the div solves the problem with Firefox. Thanks a bunch!